# I'm struggling to upgrade login script with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a custom query() function in my functions. file. I created a login.php file, but when I make a SQL query, the query() function returns a PDO object, instead of an associative array I desire. I need help to pass parameters to be bound to a stored procedure/prepared statement.

The following is the login.php file:

```
<?php

    // configuration
    require("../../includes/config.php");

    // if form was submitted
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
        // validate submission
        if (empty($_POST["username"]))
        {
            adminapologize("You must provide your username.");
        }
        else if (empty($_POST["password"]))
        {
           adminapologize("You must provide your password.");
        }

        $username = $_POST["username"];

        // query database for user
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username = '$username'";

        $result = query($sql,array($username));        
        //var_dump($result);
        //exit;

        if($sql != false)
        {
            if($result->rowCount() == 0)
            {
                printf("No admin yet.");
            }

            // if we found user, check password
            if($result->rowCount() == 1)
            {
                // first (and only) row
                $row = $result->fetch();

                // compare hash of user's input against hash that's in database
                if ($_POST["username"] == $row["username"] && crypt($_POST["password"], $row["hash"]) == $row["hash"])                 
                {
                    // remember that user is now logged in by storing user's ID in session
                    $_SESSION["admin_id"] = $row["admin_id"];

                    // redirect to admin home
                    redirect("index.php");
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // else apologize
            adminapologize("Invalid username and/or password.");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // else render form
        adminrender("login_form.php", ["title" => "Admin Log In"]);
    }

?>
```

Be advised that the config.php includes the functions.php file. And the following is the portion of the functions.php file:

```
/**
* Executes SQL statement, possibly with parameters, returning
* a pdo statement object on success, handling and halting execution on error.
*/

function query($sql, $parameters = null)
{
    static $pdo; // define the var as static so that it will persist between function calls
    try
    {
        // if no db connection, make one
        if (!isset($pdo))
        {
            // connect to database
            // you should set the character encoding for the connection
            $pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname=" . DB_NAME . ";host=" . DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // set the error mode to exceptions
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES,false); // turn emulated prepares off
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE,PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // set default fetch mode to assoc so that you don't have to explicitly list the fetch mode every place
        }

        if(empty($parameters))
        {
            // no bound inputs
            $stmt = $pdo->query($sql);
        } else {
            // has bound inputs
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            // you should use explicit bindValue() statements to bind any inputs, instead of supplying them as a parameter to the ->execute() method. the comments posted in your thread lists the reasons why.
            $stmt->execute($parameters);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        // all errors with the connection, query, prepare, and execute will be handled here
        // you should also use the line, file, and backtrace information to produce a detailed error message
        // if the error is due to a query, you should also include the $sql statement as part of the error message
        // if $pdo ($handle in your code) is set, it means that the connection was successful and the error is due to a query. you can use this to include the $sql in the error message.
        trigger_error($e->getMessage(), E_USER_ERROR);

        //exit; // note: E_USER_ERROR causes an exit, so you don't need an exit; here.
    }

    return $stmt; // if the query ran without any errors, return the pdo statement object to the calling code

}
```

Your help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You've got an excellent function, no need to spoil it.

> the query() function returns a PDO object, instead of an associative array I desire.

It's actually an object that you want to be returned. As for the array, you can simply get it by chaining fetch to the call:

```
$result = query($sql,array($username))->fetch();   // voila!
```

Look, with function returning an object you can get not only single row but dozens different kinds of results. Like single column value with `fetchColumn()` or many formats supported by `fetchAll()`. Not to mention you can get numRows() from the object while from array you can't.

With this function in its current form you can run DML queries as well, while returning fetch it will end up with error. Returning an object is a really really cool thing!

The only bad thing about your function is that you are catching an exception and converting it into an error manually, **while PHP is already doing it for you.**
Just get rid of this try catch block and you will have exactly the same (actually, even better) error reporting.

```
    // all errors with the connection, query, prepare, and execute will be handled here
    // you should also use the line, file, and backtrace information to produce a detailed error message
    // if the error is due to a query, you should also include the $sql statement as part of the error message
    // if $pdo ($handle in your code) is set, it means that the connection was successful and the error is due to a query. you can use this to include the $sql in the error message.
```

#### ALL these things PHP is already doing for you, if you simply don't catch an exception.

(save for storing an $sql variable which is not needed actually, as you can find a query following a back trace)

As of the code, it should be five times shorter:

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username = ?";
    $row = query($sql,array($username))->fetch();
    if($row && crypt($_POST["password"], $row["hash"]) == $row["hash"])
    {
         // remember that user is now logged in by storing user's ID in session
         $_SESSION["admin_id"] = $row["admin_id"];

         // redirect to admin home
         redirect("index.php");

         //this is essential as otherwise anyone will be able to proceed with this page
         exit;
    }
```

BTW, I just noticed that you are using your function wrong, sending $username right into the query. I fixed it too.

Comment: thanks for the insight. With my updated login.php, I get the correct details stored in the database, when I do var_dump($row) exit. But strangely enough, I still get the "invalid username and/or password" error message, after submitting the form.

Comment: May be it's a problem with hash. Did you try to compare one returned by crypt($_POST["password"], $row["hash"]) and $row["hash"] by var_dump-ing both?

Comment: Note that with function returning an object you can get not only single row but dozens different kinds of result. Like single column value with ->fetchColumn() or many formats supported by ->fetchAll(). Not to mention you can get numRows() from the object while from array you can't. Returning an object is a really cool thing.

Comment: I don't know how to var_dump crypt($_POST["password"], $row["hash"] and $row["hash"]. I tried this with no effect: var_dump(crypt($_POST["password"], $row["hash"])); var_dump($row["hash"]);
 exit;
            
See the modified login.php:
$sql = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username = ?";
                
$row = query($sql,array($username))->fetch();

if ($row && crypt($_POST["password"], $row["hash"]) == $row["hash"])        
{
$_SESSION["admin_id"] = $row["admin_id"];

redirect("index.php");
exit;
}

Comment: It should be outputting something. Is your crypt okay? Do you have error reporting on?

Comment: Well, when I couldn't log in to admin panel after forgetting the password, I went to phpMyAdmin and manually changed the password. I don't know if that's the cause. I'm not sure about how to turn the error reporting on.

Comment: wait. How do you change password with phpmyadmin? you're setting it in the database as is?

Comment: Yes, I typed in the password as is. I need to delete the admin account and register again, but register.php file also stopped working after upgrading to PDO. This is the insert query in the register.php file: $result = "INSERT INTO admin (username, hash, email, phone) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$email', '$phone')";. phpMyAdmin shows nothing is inserted, but var_dump($result); shows: string 'INSERT INTO admin (username, hash, email, phone) VALUES ('justinr', '$1$DZr35044$vptVigf8Uufa.vaGUAWVU.', 'justin@mydomain.com', '0851315743')' (length=143). Any idea?

Comment: With sending variables in the query as is you're NOT upgrading to PDO. It seems you have too many issues at once. I'd recommend start resolving them one by one. There is no single solution to the lost password, login script, registration script, PDO transition and password encryption at once.

Comment: I want to start with register.php and take it from there. I changed to question marks instead of variables: $sql = "INSERT INTO admin (username, hash, email, phone) VALUES ('?', '?', '?', '?')";. But nothing is inserted. var_dump outputs string 'INSERT INTO admin (username, hash, email, phone) VALUES ('?', '?', '?', '?')' (length=76). Any idea? I'm new to PDO.

Comment: Thanks for your continued support and insight. This is my insert query in register.php:
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO admin (username, hash, email, phone) VALUES (:username, :hash, :email, :phone)");
$stmt = execute(array(':username' => $username, 'hash' => $hash, ':email' => $email, ':phone' => $phone));
$affected_rows = $stmt->rowCount();.
That generates an error message: Notice: Undefined variable: pdo in /home/cmsdirectory/public/admin/register.php on line 80. Line 80 has $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO admin"). Please, guide me on that line, and I'll hopefully take it from there.

Comment: I've managed to fix the register.php with this: $query = "INSERT INTO admin (username, hash, email, phone) VALUES (:username, :hash, :email, :phone)";

            $params = array(':username' => $username, 'hash' => $hash, ':email' => $email, ':phone' => $phone);
            $result = query($query, $params);

            $affected_rows = $result->rowCount();. Now I still have issues with login.php. Any help?

Comment: @Justin yes, sure. It is rather against SO rules, but yes. May be we should move to chat with your debugging issues though.

Comment: Thanks, but when I tried, it was like I haven't made enough contributions to use chat.

Answer (score 0):

Edit according to @Your Common  Sense's answer who's absolutley right:
Call your function 'query' and do directly on that result a fetch.
For example as mentioned in the comments below:

```
$rows = query($sql, $params)->fetch();
```

If you want rows as associative array do

```
$rows = query($sql, $params)->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

This explicitly returns an associative array.

You have to fetch the result after executing.

```
$stmt->execute($parameters);
return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

This should return an associative array.

See also:  http://php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.fetch.php

```
/**
 * Executes SQL statement, possibly with parameters, returning
 * a pdo statement object on success, handling and halting execution on  error.
 */

function query($sql, $parameters = null)
{
    static $pdo; // define the var as static so that it will persist between function calls
    $return = false;
try {
// if no db connection, make one
    if (!isset($pdo)) {
    // connect to database
    // you should set the character encoding for the connection
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname=" . DB_NAME . ";host=" . DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);

    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // set the error mode to exceptions

    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES,false); // turn emulated prepares off

    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE,PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // set default fetch mode to assoc so that you don't have to explicitly list the fetch mode every place

}

if(empty($parameters)){
    // no bound inputs
    $stmt = $pdo->query($sql);
} else {
    // has bound inputs
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
     // you should use explicit bindValue() statements to bind any inputs, instead of supplying them as a parameter to the ->execute() method. the comments posted in your thread lists the reasons why.
        $stmt->execute($parameters);
        $return = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }    
} catch (Exception $e)

{
// all errors with the connection, query, prepare, and execute will be handled here
// you should also use the line, file, and backtrace information to produce a detailed error message
// if the error is due to a query, you should also include the $sql statement as part of the error message
// if $pdo ($handle in your code) is set, it means that the connection was successful and the error is due to a query. you can use this to include the $sql  in the error message.
    trigger_error($e->getMessage(), E_USER_ERROR);
    //exit; // note: E_USER_ERROR causes an exit, so you don't need an exit;     here.
}

return $return; // if the query ran without any errors, return the pdo statement     object to the calling code
```

Comment: thanks for your contribution. But adding your code right after executing the query generated an error: "undefined variable: stmt". Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You have to learn what the method chaining is. they can fetch right after execute, and fetch in **dozens** of different formats. And for this one they can just write `$row = query($sql, $params)->fetch();` and simply change it to `$row = query($sql, $params)->fetchAll();` if needed

Comment: Of course he can do it like that. But my answer was given according to the existing code.

Comment: Sorry for being harsh. I take too personal cases like this. but I should've explained better. Please see my updated answer. It's a *real* waste making such a function to return an array.

Comment: Yeah I've seen what you meant right after ma answer. Of course it'll be better to fetch after the function call ;)

Comment: Updated the answer refering to you. Hope that's finde with you